# c++ return constant 2d array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Well, I do know how to return 2d array from function:

```
struct S
{
    int a[3];
    int b[4][5];

    int const *getA() const {return a;}
    int (*getB())[5] {return b;}
};
```

The question is: how do I return **constant** 2d array? Where should I place `const` in the line

```
int (*getB())[5] {return b;}
```

?

Comment: For the sake of your sanity, use `std::array` for stuff like this.

Comment: *"I do know how to return 2d array from function"* - No, you don't, since that's not possible. What you do know is how to return a pointer to an array from a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `int`.

```
const int (*getB() const)[5] {return b;}
```

Comment: @Turgal there are other answers, that tells right things to do. My answer in simply answer to question, nothing else.

Comment: I wouldn't downvote, but strictly speaking, this does not answer OP's question, "return constant 2d array", since it only returns pointers.

Comment: @juanchopanza it's technology error of OP... It's answer to question `Where should I place const in the line ...`

Answer (score 2):

By using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead:

```
struct S
{
    using arrayA_type = std::array<int, 3>;
    using arrayB_type = std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 4>;

    arrayA_type a;
    arrayB_type b;

    const arrayA_type& getA() const { return a; }
    const arrayB_type& getB() const { return b; }
};
```

Of course you can use normal raw arrays instead, but it will be *much* easier if you use a type-alias for it, in other word no confusion where to put the `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the whole thing by using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or `std::tr1::array` or `boost::array` if you don't have C++11 support). These types are copyable, assignable, and their reference syntax is clear:

```
#include <array>

struct S
{
    std::array<int, 3> a;
    std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 4> b;

    const std::array<int, 3>& getA() const  {return a; }
    const std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 4>& getB() const { return b; }
};
```